# Webcam permission is blocked automatically in any browser for my html code

Tags: html, windows, permissions, windows-7, webcam

I am currently using windows 7 enterprise edition and i don't have admin privileges.
I cannot allow webcam permission in my html code even in online tutorials for webcam it automatically switches to blocking mode.
I tried managing exceptions, running my code in any other browser like internet explorer, google canary but nothing works !
Also my webcam and same html code works perfectly on my laptop .
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

We can't help you with this - we can't give you admin privileges on your computer. Your code works though, as you said it works on your laptop. This question has nothing to do with programming - you just don't have admin privileges.